# Specific row colouring in a Datagrid Issue

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to here is read from a file chosen in a `ComboBox` then loop the file contents adding it to a datagrid, this is working great:

```
        private void ComboBoxLoadPLFFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                var eachLine = File.ReadAllLines(@"PotentialLinksFound\" + ComboBoxLoadPLFFiles.Text);
                DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Clear();

                foreach (var row in eachLine)
                {
                    // Check for forum accounts successfully created ...
                    string[] cut = row.Split('|');
                    if (Helpers.CheckForAccountsCreated(cut[0]) == true)
                    {
                        //Helpers.ReturnMessage("Found -> " + cut[0]);
                        DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(cut[0], ComboBoxLoadPLFFiles.Text.Replace(".plf", ""), cut[1], "", cut[2]);
                        DataGridViewLinks.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(cut[0], ComboBoxLoadPLFFiles.Text.Replace(".plf", ""), cut[1], "", cut[2]);
                    }

                }
                UpdateLinksCount();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
            }
        }
```

My issue is wanted to change the row colour of certain rows depending on if `Helpers.CheckForAccountsCreated(cut[0]) == true` returns true (the logic is fine and this works as it should) but the entire gridview turns Aqua instead of a specific row, I could wait until the datagrid is populated the do a foreach but is there no way I can do it when the grid is being populated? any tips would be appreciated I'm possibly overlooking something here.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: This is a good point! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like this:

```
// get the row that you want to change color
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;

// this line here changes all the rows to Aqua
//DataGridViewLinks.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
```

When you do this:

```
DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(cut[0], ComboBoxLoadPLFFiles.Text.Replace(".plf", ""), cut[1], "", cut[2]);
```

Rows.Add() returns the index of the newest row.

We can get this index by doing:

```
int ind = DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(cut[0], ComboBoxLoadPLFFiles.Text.Replace(".plf", ""), cut[1], "", cut[2]);
```

Now we can change the color of that row like this:

```
DataGridViewLinks.Rows[ind].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
```

Comment: That worked perfect bhristov! thank you, noted for next time :)

Comment: @Graham no problem. I am glad that I could help you :)